# My output file is not displaying the solution

Tags: c++

My output file is supposed to show to answer to the function it calls on. The program runs fine, however it is not displaying the text in the "prime" function. the output file, when checked, only displays 1's. I believe this is due to the fact that its declared as a bool function, and set to return true. However, how would I get this code to return the solution in Prime to the output file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
bool prime(int);    

int main()
{
    int reader;

    ifstream Infile;
    Infile.open("numlist.txt");
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("theoutput.txt");

    while (Infile >> reader)
    {           
        outputFile << prime(reader) <<endl;    
    }
    Infile.close();
    outputFile.close();    
}

bool prime(int p)
{
    if (p % 2 == 0)
        cout << "\n" << p << "\n Is not a prime number";
    else if (p % 2 != 0)
        cout << "\n" << p << "\n is a prime number";

    return true;
}
```

No errors, however the output file is only showing 1's.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. The `prime` function always returns true. So, make it return whatever you think it needs to return. What exactly is your question?

Comment: If your `prime()` function **always** returns `true` (which it does with `return true;`), why would you expect the output to be any different than it is? The only thing you're writing to `outputFile` is the result of `prime()`, which is **always** true.

Comment: `if (p % 2 != 0)
        cout << "\n" << p << "\n is a prime number";` is not correct. There are many numbers that are not prime were this will say they are. Like 15.

Comment: The output of your `prime` function could be as simple as `return (p % 2 == 0);`. Even though this is testing if the number is even, not that its a prime number.

Comment: I decided to scrap the idea of having a cout in the prime function, instead, opting for the function to either return True or False based on the number read. The main function has the two original couts, instead, being used as outputFile<<"the statement". the program is now working and will either print that the number is prime or not prime in the output file, depending on whether the function returns true or false to the While loop in the main.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because in your `prime()` function, all the output is going to `cout` and not into `outputFile`.  The `prime()` function returns a `bool` which is what is sent to `outputFile`.

If you'd like to have output of the function go to `outputFile`, you can either pass `outputFile` as a parameter and use that instead of `cout` or make it global.

A few more comments on your code: you don't need the full `else if (p % 2 != 0)` in the else statement.  You can just use `else`, because `p % 2` is either 0 or it's not, there's no other option.

Also, strongly recommend using braces around if statements, even if they are just a single line.